# two-way multiple comparisons in R

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, tukey-hsd-test

This is a subset of my dataset:

```
> head(db,20)
   YEAR RING  CO2       Nup
1  1998    1 elev  6.441205
2  1998    2 elev  6.939212
3  1998    3  amb  6.370073
4  1998    4  amb  6.816244
5  1998    5  amb  4.839825
6  1999    1 elev  7.032590
7  1999    2 elev  7.473761
8  1999    3  amb  5.791581
9  1999    4  amb  8.209857
10 1999    5  amb  5.607706
11 2000    1 elev  9.457697
12 2000    2 elev  7.509605
13 2000    3  amb  5.938662
14 2000    4  amb  7.868018
15 2000    5  amb  8.397162
16 2001    1 elev 12.085675
17 2001    2 elev  7.136464
18 2001    3  amb  5.624912
19 2001    4  amb  7.483332
20 2001    5  amb  9.395876
```

The aim of my analysis is to find out if there is an effect of the `CO2` treatment on Nup, but furthermore, I need to know in which `YEARS` the effect of `CO2` is significant. My model would hence be:

```
mod <- lm(Nup~CO2*YEAR)
anova(mod)
```

Which renders a significant interaction. In the past I have used Tukey inside the function `glht {multcomp}`, but only with one factor. How can I do Tukey post-hoc multiple comparisons to find out what are the years in which the effect is significant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **lsmeans** package makes this pretty simple:

```
library(lsmeans)
lsmeans(mod, pairwise ~ CO2 | YEAR)
```

The tukey adjustment is the default.